# TIMESTAMPDIFF() and get None

Tags: mysql, jupyter-notebook

Why am I getting a **None** when running TIMESTAMPDIFF() in MySQL?

My query:

```
%%sql
SELECT test_name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'start_time','end_time') AS Duration
FROM exam_answers;
```

Since the start_time and end_time for every rows differ, I can't enter a value but just "start_time" and "end_time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use BACKTICKS to quote fieldname

```
SELECT test_name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`start_time`,`end_time`);
```

or you can do it without Backticks.

```
SELECT test_name, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start_time,end_time);
```

You only use Backticks if the fieldname equal a Keyword from MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) do you mean that existed column name don't need backticks to hint the database?

Comment: Yes, if you have a fieldname like date, mysql can not know what you mean. The function date or a field names date

Comment: I have re-run it and it worked! Hooray! Deepest thank!